# Databricks Filter operation giving unexpected output

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

In databricks, I am applying a filter to a dataframe to drop the rows where the columns 'UserName' and 'MachineName' match a given regular expression pattern. I noticed that it unexpectedly changed the values of another column, 'Region'. However, there is nothing in the filter logic that should affect the values of this column. The filter is specifically designed to remove rows based on the matching criteria for the two mentioned columns.

Comment: Are you using Azure databricks or AWS?

Comment: I am using Azure

Comment: please share screenshot for better understanding

Comment: @MUHAMMAD UMER can you share your code and expected output

Answer (score 0):

when the data needs to be reorganized across the partitions of the DataFrame shuffle happens

You can try and add the 'Region' column to the filter condition.

I have created an example:

```
pattern = 'user\\d'
filtered_df = df.filter(
    F.col('UserName').rlike(pattern) &
    F.col('MachineName').rlike(pattern)
)
```

In the above code defined regular expression pattern
Next applied the filter logic to drop the rows where the UserName and MachineName columns match the regular expression pattern user\d.
Then Check the values of the Region column

Results:

```
region_values = filtered_df.select('Region').distinct()
display(region_values)
```

```
Region
user1
```